# How to remove English and Spanish stop words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to delete stop words for English and Spanish. My code is working for English but not Spanish:

```
stopword = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english', 'spanish')

def remove_stopwords(text):
    text = [word for word in text if word not in stopword]
    return text
    
df['Tweet_nonstop'] = df['Tweet_tokenized'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

To get English and Spanish stopwords, you can use this:

```
stopword_en = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
stopword_es = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('spanish')
stopword = stopword_en + stopword_es
```

The second argument to `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words`, from the help, isn't another language:

```
>>> help(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words)
Help on method words in module nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist:

words(fileids=None, ignore_lines_startswith='\n') method of nltk.corpus.reader.wordlist.WordListCorpusReader instance
```

The first argument, `fileids`, can take multiple values, so, a call such as:

```
stopword = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words(fileids=('english', 'spanish'))
```

also works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

in addittion to the answer above, try

```
stopwords.words(['english','spanish'])
```